# Spring Data @EntityGraph with hibernate bytecode enhancement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE with Hibernate 5.2.4.Final with enabled bytecode enhancement (via gradle http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement-gradle). I'm using bytecode enhancement for lazy attribute loading.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements Serializable {

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
   private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "users")
    Page<Role> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

When bytecode enhancement is disabled user collection is fetched without issues, but when enhancement is inabled I've got LazyInitializationException on this collection.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Don't apply byte-code enhancement??

Comment: Great answer :)

Comment: Seriously, a need for byte-code enhancement is rare. Is there any particular reason you have it enabled?

Comment: I want to use bytecode enhancement for lazy attribute loading. For exapmle I want to load \@Lob and \@Formula fields lazily, as I understood from hibernate documentation it's not enought just to specify \@Basic(fetch=LAZY). It's also need to enable bytecode enhancement. I'm not too keen on this idea, but it seems that it's the only solution.